# JAXB warning is shown while starting my Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

JAXB warning is shown while starting my Spring Boot Application

```
WARN 854325 --- [nio-5558-exec-1] com.amazonaws.util.Base64                : JAXB is unavailable. Will fallback to SDK implementation which may be less performant.If you are using Java 9+, you will need to include javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api as a dependency.
```

How should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

In Java 9 (which brings the concept of modules), several dependencies were removed including `javax.*` one (see [JEP 320](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320)). Starting from this version, you need to add them manually.

In your case, you need to add `jaxb-api`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, you probably need to add its implementation (if you don't have it yet):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using the Spring Boot Tomcat runtime.